# Is "api1" in allowed scopes for client registration predefined in Identity server4?

Tags: asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, identityserver4

I am using Identity Server4.

I followed the QuickStarts and replicated a scenario where I have 3 web applications
1. MVC web App
2. JS web App
3. API app

I also configured ASP.Net Identity to have a persistent user and client store.

Now from Allowed scopes values for JS web App I removed a scope "api1", expecting that token generated will not have this scope value.

But when I try to login , i am not even able to view the page but getting an exception some where in the pipeline.

My previous understanding was that allowed scopes are a bunch of strings which can be used to by resource apps for authorization purpose while serving the resources .

Can any one explain why i am facing the issue or am I missing any point?

If I add "api1" scope to JS web client again I am able to view login page.

[image]

Comment: Can you enable logs

Comment: updated with the log image...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the logs. When you removed the `api1` scope from the allowed scopes from the javascript client, you removed that clients access to that scope. The application itself is requesting `api1` but it has no permissions to do so. So you need to edit the javascript clients configuration from the client side to also not request `api1`.

I am going off what you said about following the quickstart guide but where you defined your client and its configuration, it may look something like this:

```
var config = {
    authority: "http://localhost:5000",
    client_id: "js",
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:5003/callback.html",
    response_type: "id_token token",
    scope:"openid profile api1",  <--- REMOVE API1 HERE 
    post_logout_redirect_uri : "http://localhost:5003/index.html",
};
var mgr = new Oidc.UserManager(config);
```

Remember the clients have to explicitly (in most cases) express their scope requirements, if you fail any resource scope requirement it will fail the request. So you disabled the js clients allowed scope yet it was still requesting for a scope it had no access to.

Comment: yeah this is the issue ... thanks for the answer.. cant the identity server take the common scopes into consideration ? can we configure in such a way?

Comment: you mean you want to know if the js client can get all its scopes (by default) even if it doesn't know what they may be?

Comment: not exactly.. but it shouldnt throw an exception when requested.. jst ignoring the scope in the claim should be sufficient right? anyway the resource application will look for the required scopes to give access

Comment: You didn't provide details on what the exception actually was. In general though, the client requesting a scope it isn't allowed doesn't throw an exception but instead produces a 400 error with an 'invalid_scope' error. I'd suspect the exception is from your own code rather than Identity Server, but without the exception details that is just guesswork.

Comment: I never said anything about exceptions, you did. If you get a 400 that is what you have to work with. You should react to that.